# Dafny: assert that elements not accessed stay constant

Tags: dafny

Let us assume that we have an array of elements [e_1, e_2, ..., e_n] and a method only accesses (reads and writes) the first m elements of the array e.g. the method increments the first m elements of the array by one. How could the method be implemented in Dafny so that the method provides a post-condition of the form

`ensures forall i: int :: m < i <= a.Length ==> old(a[i]) == a[i]`

My current approaches did not work so I do not present them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is implementation:

```
method IncreaseByOne(a: array<int>, idx: int)
  requires 0 <= idx <= a.Length
  modifies a
  ensures forall i ::  0 <= i < idx ==> a[i] == old(a[i]) + 1
  ensures forall i ::  idx <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a[i])
{
  var t := 0;
  while t < idx
    invariant 0 <= t <= idx
    invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < t ==> a[i] == old(a[i]) + 1
    invariant forall i :: t <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a[i])
  {
    a[t] := a[t] + 1;
    t := t + 1;
  }
}
```